# Perl regex match string including newline

Tags: regex, perl

How do I match something like this:

```
haha\nhphp\nhdhd\nlolo\n
```

I want to extract between `haha` and `lolo` including the newline character, I was using the regex below but failed:

```
/haha(.*?)lolo/s
```

What I expected to be extracted:

```
\nhphp\nhdhd\n
```

I tried with the other modifiers like `//n`, `//m`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to print $1 value..

Comment: Your regex is fine -- the `/s` modifier provides that the `.` matches the new line as well. There are variations and subtleties but it should work as it stands and it does for me.  Please show your whole program, the mistake is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `(?s)` modifier

```
$x="haha\nhphp\nhdhd\nlolo\n";
$x =~ s/(?s)haha\s*(.*?)\s*lolo/$1/;
print $x;
```

or lookahad and lookbehind

```
$x="haha\nhphp\nhdhd\nlolo\n";
$x =~ m/(?s)(?<=haha)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*lolo)/;
print $1;
```

**NOTE** :- `(?s)` is DOTALL modifier. It allows to matche newline with `.`

**EDIT**

You can also use what you were using earlier (*I didn't paid attention to it*). You just need to access the first capturing group which can be done by using `$1`, `$2` etc.

```
$x =~ s/haha\s*(.*?)\s*lolo/$1/s
               <--->
                $1
```

Comment: The OP already has the `/s` modifier in their `/haha(.*?)lolo/s`

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with your code, and you should disregard the answers from others who are unfamiliar with Perl

As [**Avinash Raj** said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626969/perl-regex-match-string-including-newline#comment62736217_37626969), your regex matches your string, and all you need to do is to use the capture variable `$1`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my $s = "haha\nhphp\nhdhd\nlolo\n";

dd $1 if $s =~ /haha(.*?)lolo/s
```

#### output

```
"\nhphp\nhdhd\n"
```